# Inserción a dos tablas en una misma consulta

Tags: mysql

Deseo insertar datos a dos tablas diferentes en una misma consulta. Estas tienen en comun la columna 'id_factura'. La inserción me funciona correctamente solo en la tabla detalle_factura, pero en la tabla aux_detalle no se inserta nada.
Tampoco me aparecen errores en el javascript.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
**function insDetalle( $data ){
        require("config/config.php");
        $conn = $this->conectar();


        $sql = "INSERT INTO detalle_factura
                                (
                                    id_factura,
                                    id_producto,
                                    cantidad,
                                    precio
                                )
                                VALUES
                                (
                                    '".$this->pd($data['id_factura'])."',
                                    '".$this->pd($data['id_producto'])."',
                                    '".$this->pd($data['cantidad'])."',
                                    '".$this->pd($data['precio'])."'
                                )";
                            
        

        $retorno = $this->query_result( $conn, $sql );

        if($retorno['resultado'] == 'OK'){

            $sql = "INSERT INTO aux_detalle
        
                                (
                                    id_factura,
                                    id_persona
                                )
                                VALUES
                                (
                                    '".$this->pd($data['id_factura'])."',
                                    '".$this->pd($data['id_persona'])."'
                                )";

            $this->commit($conn);
        }else{
            $this->rollback($conn);
        }
        $this->desconectar($conn);
        return $retorno;
    }**
```

Comment: $retorno donde asignas el valor OK, es un array asociativo o una variable string simple?

Comment: es un array asociativo si

Comment: Puedes probar a simplemente ejecutar la funcion `$this->query_result( $conn, $sql );` y dentro esa esa funcion **query_result** asignarle el 'OK' , ya que al hacer que $retorno sea igual a esa función estara dando problemas.

Comment: a lo mejor sería buena idea ejecutar commit después de insertar en la segunda? sólo como sugerencia